# Images change color on device and in simulator

Tags: colors, sprite-kit

So I have this image:
[image]

And it changes colors on devices, the top logo should be red-orange, the three buttons on the left blue and the three on the bottom orange and they are on my computer and in Illustrator and Photoshop, but when I add it to the scene as a spritenode it changes. Why is this happening? The colors change on a device and in the simulator

For some reason it changed colors here as well... Is this another "The Dress"

It's in JPEG

Comment: What image format are you using?

Comment: That was it, I was using JPEG

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you're using JPEG. Use PNG instead